# Javascript add param when calling a callback function

Tags: javascript, function, validation, callback

I want to set additional Parameters to callback function when defining it.

```js
// min Length validator
function minLengthValidator(input, minLength) {
    console.log("Length is", input.length, "min Length is", minLength);
    return input.length >= minLength;
}

// using the callback in an validate function (e.g. on an Input field) and only give it the input value
function validate(callback) {
    let exampleInput = "myText";
    let valid = callback(exampleInput);
    return valid;
}

// call the validate function
validate(minLengthValidator);
```

But how do I set the minLength property on the `minLengthValidator` function? The value gets passed in by the validate function but how to pass the minLength?

You can always define a custom function for each and call the minLengthValidator function in it:

```js
validate((value) => { return minLengthValidator(value, 4);});
```

but is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functional programming gives us the tools to solve this easily.

```
// min Length validator
function minLengthValidator(minLength) {
    return function(input) {
        console.log("Length is", input.length, "min Length is", minLength);
        return input.length >= minLength;
    }
}

validate(minLengthValidator(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can switch the order of parameters for `minLengthValidator`, then use [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to set the value of the first parameter.

```js
function minLengthValidator(minLength, input) {
    console.log("Length is", input.length, "min Length is", minLength);
    return input.length >= minLength;
}
function validate(callback) {
    let exampleInput = "myText";
    let valid = callback(exampleInput);
    return valid;
}
console.log(validate(minLengthValidator.bind(null, 4)));
```

Comment: Good answer, works, but I don't like to bind `null` to every call. I know I didn't clarify my use case but later it will be an `validators` array with the functions and then binding `null` to every entry is not what I want. But thanks for your Answer! Learned something new!

Comment: @Tim-Gabrikowski `null` here just sets the `this` context for the function. You don't use the `this` value at all, so it doesn't affect anything (only the arguments to bind after the 1st argument affect the parameter values). But what style you use is up to you.

Comment: Can you tell me how I would do it with multiple parameters like if I want to build just a `length` validator that takes the `min` and `max` length as parameters? Do you have an Idea for that?

Comment: @TimGabrikowski It's the same idea: just `lengthValidator.bind(null, 3, 5)` for example where `lengthValidator` takes two arguments in the order of min, max.